# jQuery plugin to turn a list into a marquee-like carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel, marquee

Does anyone know a good jQuery plugin to turn a list of images into an autoscrolling marquee-like carousel? Seems simple but I haven't been able to find a decent one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Seems simple but I haven't been able to find a decent one_. Mmmm... seems like there are [loooots](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=images+carousel+jquery) of options.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, I just put the straight Google link instead. I mean this questions it's a clear _let me google that for you_ kinda thing...

Comment: @elclanrs that's ok if you didn't know.  Now you do :).  And even though I agree with you that it's easy to search for something like this, I still agree with SO on this one.  Cheers though!  Now I +1'd your comment lol

Comment: You should google and try to implement one of your own first and then if you have a issue in it post the issue, rather than asking what are the good plugins

Comment: I don't even know what he means by "marquee" carousel lol

Comment: I think by _marquee-like_ he means a carousel that starts automatically, basically all of them have this option AFAIK.

Comment: ahh gotcha.  yeah basically every single one of them has that feature..

Comment: @mmmshuddup marquee is a html tag which allows the content inside it to scroll either side just like in a image slide scroller

Comment: @Swarnajith thanks.  I have never used that tag before.  Seems kinda old school in my opinion..

Answer (score 1):

Marquee is an 'old' word to be searched now :) We used to use it in the FrontPage era when IE was the ruler.

Anyways, you might search for news ticker like this one http://164a.com/jnewsticker/